# Count number of 1's in an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A`. I want to count the number of 1's in the array but I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

B=np.count(A==1)
print(B)
```

The error is

```
in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'count'
```

The expected output is

```
7
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `np.count` function does not exist, you can use `np.count_nonzero` instead.

```py
import numpy as np

A=np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

B=np.count_nonzero(A==1) # or just A, if you'll never have anything other than 0 or 1
print(B)
```